What's the best way split users into random groups
So here's my current problem is we are trying to implement a way to do AB testing. In my opinion the best way to separate users is probably by ID. Basically I would need to map their ID to a boolean (A or B/true or false).
The main problem I have with this though is I would want a method that can give different combinations for different AB testing scenarios. If I do something simple like convert to an Integer mod 2, it becomes difficult to use a parameter to create different groups (mathematically its difficult to make only some of the 1s go to 0 and vice versa even before the mod operation).
I think this leaves me with using a proper hashing algorithm like SHA1 but I figured I would ask if anyone else has a good way of doing this as well.

For AB combination 1 - hash username + nickname + Id; for AB combination 2 hash nickname + username + id; for AB combination 3 hash Id + nickname + userName, etc. then use last digit of hash even/odd to decide

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'd start with:
Boolean b = Math.mod(Math.abs(u.Username.hashCode()), 2) == 0;

as user names have to be unique and don't change. And running something like this in the Developer Console to check that the distribution is as expected:
Boolean[] bs = new Boolean[] {};
for (User u : [select Username from User]) {
    Boolean b = Math.mod(Math.abs(u.Username.hashCode()), 2) == 0;
    bs.add(b);
}
System.debug('>>> ' + JSON.serialize(bs));


Makes sense. The only issue is that I can't use different "seeds" for different reordering. Essentially I'm trying to create testing groups for different features. Right now this would mean that one group gets all A features and one group gets all B feature as opposed to a mix.

One simple way to do it I have used is to just assign a random number to each member in the list based on the list size
e.g.
User A : 4
User B : 1
User C : 3
User D : 2
Then assign based on even vs odd number.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want it to be reproducable, so the same contact would go to the same group under multiple invocations.
